# Using preg_replace_callback to make links out of MySQL Query! Help Please

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I am currently using for the code and it's not working right.

I've tried making sense of literature and it's not clicking

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","----","----");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("----", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

$str = 'post_content';

$str = preg_replace_callback('#(?:https?://\S+)|(?:www.\S+)|(?:\S+\.\S+)#', function($arr)
{
    if(strpos($arr[0], 'http://') !== 0)
    {
        $arr[0] = 'http://' . $arr[0];
    }
    $url = parse_url($arr[0]);

    // images
    if(preg_match('#\.(png|jpg|gif)$#', $url['path']))
    {
        return '<img src="'. $arr[0] . '" />';
    }
    // youtube
    if(in_array($url['host'], array('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com'))
      && $url['path'] == '/watch'
      && isset($url['query']))
    {
        parse_str($url['query'], $query);
        return sprintf('<iframe class="embedded-video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $query['v']);
    }
    //links
    return sprintf('<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', $arr[0]);
}, $str);

echo $str;
echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I know the problem is with $str = 'post_content'; obviously it just shows a line for each line in mysql with just post_content.

What I want it to do is show all the values from the row post_content in MySQL and display the links as links , the youtube videos as youtube vids and the images and  and so forth, but it's not converting it.

Can anyone see what I am missing? If you could explain the tree of how it calls out that too I would love you greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column `post_content` and want to fetch it, then instead of using the assignment `$str = 'post_content';` use:

```
 $str = $row['post_content'];
```